# How to add duration for input.ondown in phaser?

Tags: phaser-framework

How can I add a duration to the `this.input.onDown()` event in Phaser so that if a user clicks for say 10ms action "A" should happen and if the click is prolonged then action "B" should happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (this.input.activePointer.duration > 10 && this.input.activePointer.duration < 25) {
    // do action "A"
}
else if (this.input.activePointer.duration > 25) {
    // do action "B"
}
```

Put this inside `update()` or wrap it in a function that you call from there.
It should work for the last active pointer if you have multiple (e.g. on mobile).